# validate response before caching with Cloudflare page rule

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I’ve created a Cloudflare page rule to cache a static page as follows:

```
domain.com/
Cache Level: cache everything
Edge Cache TTL: 2 hours
```

There’s generally no problem, but several times the server has returned an error, or there’s been a connection timeout, and Cloudflare has cached this result. How can I test for a valid response before caching the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check the status of the response before you do any caching.

[response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) returns true if the status code is within 200 to 299. You can interrogate the status directly with [response.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status)

```
const response = await fetch(event.request);
if(response.ok) {
    // ... do caching logic
}
```